# Union polygons by intersection lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, intersection, polygon-creation

I have two layers:

- contiguous polygons without properties
- lines with the name property that overlaps the polygons

I want to get a new layer of joined polygons if they are crossed by the same line and secondly, apply the properties of the line to the underlying polygons

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the ["Join Attributes by Location"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-location) tool via `Vector -> Data Management Tools -> Join Attributes by Location`.

For your specific needs, I would suggest starting with the following settings:

[image]

Comment: I get a good result if I also activate the option in the polygon layer: Advanced Option -> Invalid feature filtering -> Skip

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers).

Go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the following query. Modify the name of the layers and feel free to add more line attributes.

You can then persist the layer if you wish.

```sql
SELECT ln.name, st_union(p.geometry)
FROM myLineLayer ln
JOIN myPolygonLayer p
  ON st_intersects(p.geometry, ln.geometry)
GROUP BY ln.name --only if multiple line have the same name
```